# Facebook post url when redirected to mobile url not working

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, mobile

I have a facebook application that stores post and comment details using the facebook graph api. The graph api gives urls to posts and the urls come back using the web based url. My app allows me to search for content in wall posts and I return the url of a post that matches my search term.

For example a url to a post is in the form

```
http://www.facebook.com/user_id/posts/post_id
```

On the desktop this works ok. On my mobile I think facebook redirects to a mobile version of the url.

Example, I request

```
www.facebook.com/user_id/posts/post_id
```

Facebook redirects to

```
m.facebook.com/user_id/posts/post_id
```

I have confirmed the redirect using an agent changer on Firefox on my desktop and I get the same error message which is.

> The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be
>   temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or
>   expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.

My questions is:
Should the mobile url for facebook posts work with the redirect. For example when I try

```
m.facebook.com/my_username
```

this comes back no problem. Am I missing a setting or configuration to get this working

Comment: I've managed to find a work around by rewriting the facebook web url to a mobile equivalent. I'm not sure I trust this or if its correct but it seems to work. If anyone can suggest a better way I'd appreciate the advice. For a url of <www.facebook.com/1234/posts/789> I rewrote this to a mobile equivalent of <m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=789&id=1238&__user=888> where 888 is the facebook user id of the user logged into your application

Comment: The above works for me without the __user=.  Good job

Comment: I am experiencing something similar, but cant get it to work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265059/facebook-share-error-the-page-you-requested-cannot-be-displayed-right-now?noredirect=1#comment65910825_39265059