# Facebook share error : "the page you requested cannot be displayed right now"

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used custom stories to do the facebook share and the share happens correctly and displays in posted user's facebook wall. See below:

[image]

The issue when when I click on the name of the page ("page" in the picture), via the facebook mobile app it gives me the following error:

```
the page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page
```

The link entered for `"Site URL"` in facebook application opens when I click on "Page"("page" in the picture) from machine browser but not with mobile facebook app. Any help is really appreciated since there is no / very less information about this issue.

Comment: So this links to the canvas address of your app? Canvas is not available on mobile, you need to specify a Mobile Site URL in the canvas settings, then mobile users following the link will be redirected there. Currently you also need to get your app white-listed for that, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/

Comment: Ido you mean I have to add platform canvas? and add the url there too?

Comment: I asked where the link takes you to, and assumed it was canvas. If it is something else …

Comment: link is not taking me anywhere. What ideally should happen is it should open the facebook page. What happens now is I am getting this message : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003559/android-facebook-sdk-sso-the-page-you-requested-cannot-be-displayed

Comment: I meant where does it take you on desktop?

Comment: to my web site. I have provided it under Site URL.

Comment: Are you using tagging/mentioning in your OG action to get it to say “with page” there?

Comment: the post says "Visura Thilan booked a class in XXXX with YYYY"
here booked is the action. YYYY is the name of the app.

Comment: @CBroe any suggestions? I tried with canvas too. still the link does not open in phone. But works fine in PC.

Comment: With Canvas, your Mobile Site URL might still need to be whitelisted, as mentioned in first comment.

Comment: @CBroe please tell me what whitelisting is?

Comment: Again: See the bug report that I linked to.

Comment: @CBroe I read each and every comment of the bug report. Is it related to my issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122498/discussion-between-tharakanirmana-and-cbroe).

Comment: If you want the automatic redirect of mobile users that try to access your canvas URL to the mobile site URL to work - then you need to fill out the form mentioned there in the top response.

Comment: but the thing is my app does not use canvas. That is why I am wondering if the bug report is related to my issue. @CBroe any thoughts?

Comment: You said you tried with canvas, so my comments were in regard to that.

Comment: @CBroe I have not mentioned that I am using canvas anywhere in the thread. Anyhow what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to yourfacebook App dashboard
2. Go to Settings
3. Then switch to `YES` **Single Sign On**
4. Then switch to `YES` **Deep Linking**